# Using multiple timers in Allegro 5

Tags: c++, timer, allegro

I watched multiple tutorials about using multiple timers in Allegro, but that way of programming doesn't work for me. 
The problem is that the source adress never matches to the timer adress i want to watch.

I use multiple classes/instances to encapsulate my code, because it will be very complex in the future. The main loop of my game is located in the Game class/instance. The timers and the events are encapsulated in an Engine class/instance, that is a member of the Game instance.

**Game.cpp:**

```
void Game::GameLoop() {   
  al_wait_for_event(GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent_queue, &GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent);

  if (GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
  {
    // DEBUG: EVENT SOURCE ADRESSES DON'T MATCH TO THE TIMER ADRESSES
    std::cout << "TimerEvent: " << GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent.timer.source << " " << GameEngine.VSyncTimer << " " << GameEngine.LoopTimer << " " << GameEngine.InGameTimer << "\n";

    if (GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent.timer.source == GameEngine.InGameTimer) 
    { 
        std::cout << "InGameTimerEvent"; 
    }
    if (GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent.timer.source == GameEngine.VSyncTimer) 
    { 
        std::cout << "VSyncTimerEvent"; 
    }
    if (GameEngine.LoopTimerEvent.timer.source == GameEngine.LoopTimer) 
    { 
        std::cout << "LoopTimerEvent"; 
    }
  }  
}
```

**Engine.cpp:**

```
Engine::Engine() {
  if (al_init()) std::cout << "allegro initialized\n";
  else std::cout << "failed to initialize allegro!\n";

  if (InitTimer()) std::cout << "Timer initialized\n";
  else std::cout << "failed to initialize timer!\n";

  LoopTimerEvent_queue = al_create_event_queue();

  al_register_event_source(LoopTimerEvent_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(LoopTimer));
  al_register_event_source(LoopTimerEvent_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(VSyncTimer));
  al_register_event_source(LoopTimerEvent_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(InGameTimer));
  std::cout << "Event queues initialized\n"; 
}


bool Engine::InitTimer() {
  LoopTimer = al_create_timer(1.0);
  if (!LoopTimer) 
  {
    std::cout << "failed to initialize LoopTimer!\n";
    return false;
  }

  InGameTimer = al_create_timer(1.0 / m_iTimeScale);
  if (!InGameTimer)
  {
    std::cout << "failed to initialize InGameTimer!\n";
    return false;
  }

  VSyncTimer = al_create_timer(1.0 / FPS);
  if (!VSyncTimer)
  {
    std::cout << "failed to initialize VSyncTimer!\n";
    return false;
  }

  al_start_timer(LoopTimer);
  al_start_timer(VSyncTimer);
  al_start_timer(InGameTimer);
  std::cout << "Timers started\n";

  return true;
}
```

**Engine.h:**

```
class Engine {
public:
  ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* pDisplay = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_TIMER* VSyncTimer = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_TIMER* LoopTimer = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_TIMER* InGameTimer = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_EVENT LoopTimerEvent;
  ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE* LoopTimerEvent_queue = NULL;

  Logger EngineLogger;
  EventHandler GameEvents;

  private:
  double m_iTimeScale = 2.0;

public:
  Engine();
  ~Engine();

  bool InitEngine();
  bool InitTimer();
  bool InitDisplay();

  void UpdateDisplay();

  float GetTimeScale();
  void SetTimeScale(float timescale);
};
```

**Output**
`TimerEvent: 031A0D80 0326AF30 0326A380 0326B090`

"TimerEvent: " [actual event adress] [VSyncTimer adress] [LoopTimer adress] [InGameTimer adress]

Where is the problem with these adresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally initialized the timers instance twice, which created new timers with (of course) different adresses. But in the event queue the OLD ones were registered, because of my stupid organization. I fixed that by putting the queue registration to the InitTimer function and fixed the bug with the double timer initialization.
Now everything works perfectly!